# Simple loading bar

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a simple download bar, but it turns out only a solid color without transition animation.
In addition, the "repeating-linear-gradient" does not work and I cannot understand why.

I am hope for your help. Thank you!

```css
.Download {
  height: 80px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  /*background: repeating-linear-graient (90deg, blue, red, 100px);*/
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue, red);
  animation-name: download;
  animation-direction: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes download {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Download">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo code to achieve this.

```css
.Download {
  height: 80px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Download:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue, red);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  animation: download 5s;
}

@keyframes download {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Download">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make half the linear gradient transparent (a bit list to prevent a hole in the end). Set the background position x to 100% to present only the transparent part. Then animation to 0:

```css
.Download {
  height: 80px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0, blue 50.02%, transparent 50.02%) no-repeat;
  animation: download 10s forwards;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
}

@keyframes download {
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Download">
</div>
```